# Magento 1 Stock Status

Tags: magento-1, stock, out-of-stock, stock-status

I am trying to figure a way to hide show stock status/availability on product page unless it is out of stock. I have all the settings configured to where it displays stock status on front end as normal, however I don't want to show "In Stock" only if the item is out of stock then I want it to display Availability "Out of Stock" only. A lot of our items are ordered through other vendors and drop shipped to customer therefore I don't want to display stock status on those items. Only the items we exclusively ship from our location.

Comment: paste your `view.phtml` code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide stock status on "In Stock" products, you can comment code for instock in following file:

app/design/frontend/{{Theme_Package}}/{{Theme_Name}}/template/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml

code will be look like after Changes:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
    <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
            <!-- <p class="availability in-stock">
                 <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?></span>
                 <span class="value"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock') ?></span>
            </p> -->
        <?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock">
        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?></span>
        <span class="value"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock') ?></span>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now Stock status shows only on Out of Stock Products

Comment: Thanks, It Works, Just what I was looking for. Now I need to change the color to red or make it bolder to where it will stand out some. Text is small and light. Need it to be seen since the add to cart is missing and they wonder why there is no way to checkout

Comment: Please upvote my answer if this helpful you.

Comment: Will this same code work on a Magento 2 Site once we complete and launch. If so what folder location and file.

Comment: For Magento 2 you will find that file here, but you need to copy that file in your theme.
Please copy "default.phtml" file from "/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type"
and paste it here: "/app/design/frontend/{{Theme_Package}}/{{Theme_Name}}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/"