# Magento 2 Which file stores the "in inventory" product view?

Tags: magento2, inventory

I am trying to figure a way to hide show stock status/availability on product page.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

If you want to change this text only for product details page and for that section which you mentioned then you need to copy the following file to your theme:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

You theme file location will be like below:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

And update the text.

**Method 2:**

Create one en_US.csv on your theme like below:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/i18n/en_US.csv

And add the translation text like "In stock","Salable"

Comment: That will not hide the text..

Comment: U want to show/hide based on what?? You can put your condition in template

Comment: I need to use the logic which was raised in this post: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247059/magento-1-stock-status
But on Magento 2

Comment: where is vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml located ?

in app/design/frontend/vendor ?
?

Comment: Vendor directory is in root of magento

Comment: Override this file in your file as a explained in answer and comment in-stock logic code