# Magento 2 Stock Status

Tags: magento2, stock, out-of-stock, stock-status

This question has been answered for Magento 1. (see: [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247059/magento-1-stock-status/348431#348431)).
As I am migrating to Magento2 and need the same logic here is the issue:

I am trying to figure a way to hide show stock status/availability on the product page unless it is out of stock. I have all the settings configured to where it displays stock status on the front end as normal, however, I don't want to show "In Stock" only if the item is out of stock then I want it to display Availability "Out of Stock" only. A lot of our items are ordered through other vendors and drop-shipped to the customer therefore I don't want to display stock status on those items. Only the items we exclusively ship from our location.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to hide the stock status when it would show "In Stock", you could add a CSS rule:

```
.product-info-stock-sku .available {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In stock/Out of stock is shown from template file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml`

You need to add this template file in your custom theme and make your changes there.

You can add this file in your theme at location `app/design/frontend/Vendor/custom_theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml`

In this template file, value of `$_product->isAvailable()` will be true if product is in stock.

Comment: sorry wrong phrasing. Right phrasing of question is in post: 348444